# Rails 4 AJAX doesn't update session's var

Tags: jquery, ajax, session, ruby-on-rails-4

I have problem, when I try update session in Rails 4 via AJAX. I have some coffescript:

```
ready = ->
$('#_usa-shipping_free').change (event) ->
  if $('#_usa-shipping_free').prop('checked')
    select_wrapper = $('#shipping-wrapper')

    select_wrapper.empty

    url = "/shipping_cart?shipping_type=free&remote=true"

    select_wrapper.load(url)
    updateTotal()
  return

$('#_usa-shipping_priority').change (event) ->
  if $('#_usa-shipping_priority').prop('checked')
    select_wrapper = $('#shipping-wrapper')

    select_wrapper.empty

    url = "/shipping_cart?shipping_type=priority&remote=true"

    select_wrapper.load(url)
    updateTotal()
  return

updateTotal = ->
  $.ajax(
    url: "http://localhost:3000/order/get_total",
    contentType: 'text/plain'
  ).success (data) ->
    $("#order-total").html("Total $" + data.total)
    return
  .fail ->

return

$(document).ready(ready)
$(document).on('page:load', ready)
```

And controller action:

```
def shipping_cart(shipping_type = params[:shipping_type])

  if shipping_type == 'international'
    session[:shipping_cost] = Order::INTERNATIONAL_SHIPPING_COST
  elsif shipping_type == 'priority'
    session[:shipping_cost] = Order::PRIORITY_SHIPPING_COST
  else
    session[:shipping_cost] = Order::FREE_SHIPPING_COST
  end
  if params[:remote]
    render partial: 'shipping_cart'
    return
  end
end
```

This code must update a field with total amount of order, based on radiobuttons which contains options for shipping. Instead of this it not works anyway. If I delete calls of updateTotal() it's work next: open page -> select radio -> refresh page -> total was recounted. But I need it in AJAX. I use session for TOTAL and SHIPPING_COST.

This is my GET_TOTAL action:

```
  def get_total
    total = 0.to_f
    books = Book.all
    books.each do |book|
      if session[:cart].include? book.id
        total = total + book.price.to_f
      end
    end
    if session[:discount_code] != nil && session[:discount_code].blank? == false
      discount_code = DiscountCode.find_by_code(session[:discount_code])
      unless discount_code.nil?
        unless discount_code.fixed_discount.blank?
          total = total - discount_code.fixed_discount
        else
          total = total - (total / 100 * discount_code.discount_percents  )
        end
      end
    end
    total = total + session[:shipping_cost].to_f
    total = total.round(2)
    session[:total] = total
    output = {'total' => "#{total}"}.to_json
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: output, status: 200 }
      format.html { total }
    end
 end
```

Before every action, except SUBMIT (in it I trying to use all this feature), I set SHIPPING_COST in 0.

When I try show shipping_cost to console with puts session[:shipping_cost], in shipping_cart I get right value, but in get_total - 0.

Sometimes feature works, but it one of several times and it works that I click on FREE_SHIPPING, but my TOTAL came as plus PRIORITY_SHIPPING.

Here is my SUBMIT ACTION, maybe it helps:

```
  def submit
    session[:order_id] = params[:order_id]
    @order = Order.find(session[:order_id])
    @order.total = get_total
    books = Book.all
    books.each do |book|
      if session[:cart].include? book.id
        @order.books << book
      end
    end
    @order.save
    @books = Book.all
    @total = get_total
    @shipping_types = get_types_of_shipping(@order.country)
    puts @order.country
    if @order.country == 'United States'
      session[:shipping_type] = 'free'
    else
      session[:shipping_type] = 'international'
    end
    shipping_cart(session[:shipping_type])
    puts session[:shipping_type]
    puts session[:shipping_cost]
                                                                                   end
```

Comment: What does the Rails log show when the AJAX option is called?

Answer (score 0):

```
Started GET "/shipping_cart?shipping_type=priority&remote=true" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-                 14 10:49:56 +0300
Processing by OrdersController#shipping_cart as HTML
Parameters: {"shipping_type"=>"priority", "remote"=>"true"}
Rendered orders/_shipping_cart.html.haml (1.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 5ms (Views: 4.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/order/get_total" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-14 10:49:57 +0300
Processing by OrdersController#get_total as */*
Book Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "books".* FROM "books"
Completed 200 OK in 3ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.6ms)
```

This is log of AJAX call. Some interesting that in different calls order of calls are not same. E.g. in one call there is

```
Started GET "/shipping_cart?shipping_type=priority&remote=true" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-                 14 10:49:56 +0300
```

and then

```
Started GET "/order/get_total" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-14 10:49:57 +0300
```

But in other order its conversely.

There is a notice. In log of Rails all calls end with Completed 200 OK. But in Chrome it 304 Not Modified. And one of few is 200 OK (which works, but not right).